# Is Jennifer Mason really Troubled?

Tags: sy-fy, haven

*Some spoilers for Haven S4*

By early *Haven* Season 4, we had learnt that:

> Jennifer Mason's blood is able to activate/is absorbed by the Crocker Trouble.

We had also "learned" that Jennifer's birth parents were Haven natives, Mr. and Mrs. Stevens and hence the implication was that Jennifer was Troubled, with her Trouble being a connection to the Barn. This fit completely with the fact of her blood giving the Crocker's a high, a property of Troubled blood only.

But later in the season we learned that:

> 1. Jennifer is actually from The Other World.
> 2. Troubles were given to Earth-people by people from the Other World using the black goo.

At this point, the Stevens being Jennifer's parents seems to be false back-story built by Agent Howard when he placed Jennifer up for adoption.

As such, do we have any information on whether Jennifer was really Troubled or not?

Or does the blood of anyone from the Other World (ie. Mara, William, Dave) behave the same as blood of the Troubled humans if a Crocker touches it?

ETA: For an answer, I am looking for any information regarding this from creator/actor tweets, official info released or info from any of the comics.

Additionally, if there is any canon instance of blood from William, Mara or Dave touching a Crocker but *not* having any effect, that would also seem to be sufficient for the idea that the effect of Jennifer's blood on Wade was due to the Troubles and not a product of her being from the Other World. So I'll be glad to take any such instance in canon as an answer as well.