# Where was Jennifer from?

Tags: haven

In the question [Is Jennifer Mason really Troubled?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67811/is-jennifer-mason-really-troubled), the basis of this seems to be that Jennifer is from

> the same world as Mara, William, et al.

I can't seem to find any evidence for that. Or anything on her birth, other than being birthed to the Stevens family and hidden by Agent Howard, as we discover in [Crush](http://havenmaine.wikia.com/wiki/Crush), <sub>(Season 4, Episode 8)</sub>:

[image]

**So where did Jennifer come from?** Admittedly, I haven't watched Season 4 since it aired, so I may be missing something obvious.